# String Replace UFT-8 and ApphaNumeric In php?

Tags: php, regex

**Input string:**

```
$string  =  "Dinesh G தினேஷ் ";
```

I Would Like to Convert this string into

```
<span class="english">Dinesh</span> <span class="english">G</span> தினேஷ்
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you actually tried something? SO isn't a "*give me code*" sort of platform, you're expected to show your own effort (and by effort, that's code) and a specific problem with a description *which parts of **your code** isn't working*.

Comment: @Qirel  i don't think people are listening you. Neither OP nor others (giving answer)

Comment: Thing is, it's not an "issue". It's a request for code, which is off-topic for this platform. From the tour, there's even a section which specifically says "*Don't ask about questions you haven't **tried** to find an answer for (show your work!)*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplest code, It will check for characters `A-Z` , `a-z` then we capture those words and replace them with span tags around it.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/791869)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string  =  "Dinesh G தினேஷ் ";
echo preg_replace("/([A-Za-z]+)/", '<span class="english">$1</span>', $string);
```

**Output:**
`<span class="english">Dinesh</span> <span class="english">G</span> தினேஷ்`

Comment: Really Thank you So Much Sahil Gulati.... Please tell me if Number also should replace the string..

Comment: No, my current post will replace only english words. with span tags around it.

Comment: @DineshG Please share the expected input and output for that.